# Linker command failed with exit code 1 but I only tried to compile 1 simple cpp file

Tags: c++, macos, linker

```
class cls {
public:
  cls(  );
  cls(int x);
};

int x;
int* y = &x;

int main(  )
{
  // The following are unambiguously expressions, constructing instances of cls.  cls(int(x));
  cls(*static_cast<int*>(y));
}
```

I am trying the above code from a textbook but weirdly I got this error when running the command `g++ test.cpp -v`

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx13.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -fobjc-msgsend-selector-stubs -target-sdk-version=13.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +crc -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +ras -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +sm4 -target-feature +sha3 -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 820.1 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro "-fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/sinchunyeung/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/UST/COMP2011/practice" -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/f3/h4301l8d7hn_1612_5g5hpmw0000gn/T/test-14473d.o -x c++ test.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 13.1 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/f3/h4301l8d7hn_1612_5g5hpmw0000gn/T/test-14473d.o -lc++ -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cls::cls(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-14473d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Your constructors are declared but nowhere defined. Did you mean `cls(int x) {};`?

Comment: Linker can not link calls of constructor tthat you did not define.

Comment: `*static_cast<int*>(y))`? Why? `y` have the type `int*` already, so casting it to the same type makes no sense. And why the pointer in the first place? Don't just add things to code if you get an error you don't understand, especially if you don't understand the code you're adding.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code is written to investigate whether cls(x) will be treated as a declaration of cls or an expression (in contrast to the one with static_cast which is surely an expression). I forgot to put the curly braces for the two constructor though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried on my compiler and `cls(x)` will be treated as a variable declaration with a redundant pair of parentheses. The behavior is different with the cast though.

Comment: I was wrong. It's context-sensitive.